Convolution yielding weird arctan term
Okay, so I have the following problem. I would like to calculate the following convolution:
$$s(t) =  g(t) \ast e^{-at} = \int_0^{t} g(t-t') e^{-at'} dt'$$
Now, I'm going to let $g(t)=a\sin(\theta)$, with $\frac{d\theta}{dt} = \omega$, where $\omega$ is the angular frequency.
Now, when I calculate this convolution, either using the convolution theorem (is possible even though the sine is not square integrable) or in the regular way by simply computing the integral, it gives me:
$$\frac{2a\omega}{\omega^2 + a^2}\sin(\theta)$$.
I have been led to believe that this is wrong and that the result should be
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\frac{\omega}{a})^2 + 1}}sin(\theta - \arctan(\frac{\omega}{a}))$$.
What am I missing?
Edit: Okay, so here is what I did. My suspicion is that something is quite obviously very wrong.
Chose $a=\frac{1}{\tau}$ Now, again we let $\theta = \omega t$, with the derivative above. Then:
$$g(t) = \frac{1}{\tau} \int_0^T \sin(\omega(t-t')) \exp(\frac{-t'}{\tau})dt'$$
We now substitute $u'=\omega t'$ to yield
$$g(t) = \frac{1}{\omega \tau} \int_0^{\frac{U'}{\omega}} \sin(\omega t-u')) \exp(\frac{-u'}{\omega\tau})du'$$
Good so far?
Then we can expand the $\sin$ using the well-known trig identity:
$$$g(t) = \frac{1}{\omega \tau} \int_0^{\frac{U'}{\omega}} (\sin(\omega t)\cos(u')-\cos(\omega t)\sin(u'))( \exp(\frac{-u'}{\omega\tau})du'$$
Now, I'm a bit stuck. If the bounds of integration where the two infinities, I could solve by using the oddness of the sine function. Here it seems like I can only solve the integral in the second term. So I now have:
$$\frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega \tau} \int_0^{\frac{U'}{\omega}} \cos(u')( \exp(\frac{-u'}{\omega\tau})du' - \frac{\cos(\omega t)}{\omega \tau} \int_0^{\frac{U'}{\omega}} \sin(u')( \exp(\frac{-u'}{\omega\tau})du'$$
Supposing that $\exp(\circ)$ is almost 0 enough at $\frac{U'}{\omega^2 \tau}$ and using integration by parts twice I will get for the left part (other one is analogous, we only swap -$\cos$ for the $\sin$) a term of the form $$\frac{1}{1 + \omega^2 \tau^2} \frac{\sin(\omega t)}{\omega \tau}$$.
Now this stumps me.

Why the downvote? This is not homework. I'll be happy to share my calculations.

I edited the post to include calculations.

For $$g(t)=a \sin (\omega t)$$ Mathematica gives the result $$\int\limits_0^t g(t-\tau), e^{-a \tau } , d\tau =\frac{a \left(\omega e^{-a t}+a \sin(\omega t)-\omega \cos(\omega t)\right)}{a^2+\omega^2}.$$

I found the solution: one must use the identities $\sin(\arctan(\omega \tau))= \frac{\tau \omega}{\sqrt{1+(\tau \omega)^2}}$and $\cos(\arctan(\omega \tau))= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(\tau \omega)^2}}$. Additionally, there were some slight mistakes in the above computation, together again with the trig identity from above.

I ignored the exponential term, because I'm interested in the behavior when $t$ is quite large compared with the time constant.
